# JavaScript Percentage Calculation on JSON Response

Tags: javascript, api

We're using a Booking Engine that retrieved Data and Promo codes from the REDZY API and we're currently struggling to have percentage amounts working.

Here our current code

```
...
var tour_id = $('input[name="tour_id"]').val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: { action: 'verify_promo_code', promocode: promocode, tour_id: tour_id },
  url: orpheus_tours_local_var.ajaxurl,
  success: function (response) {
    if (response) {
      var responseJson = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(responseJson);
      var discountValue
      if(responseJson.result.valueType == 'VALUE') {
          discountValue = responseJson.result.value;
      }
      else if (responseJson.result.valueType == 'PERCENT_LIMITPRODUCT') {
          discountValue = $('.grand-total').html().replace('$','');
      }
      else if (responseJson.result.valueType == 'VALUE_LIMITPRODUCT') {
          discountValue = responseJson.result.value;
      }
      else if (responseJson.result.valueType == 'VALUE_LIMITCATALOG') {
          discountValue = responseJson.result.value;
...
```

While we're not having any issues with all fixed Value related items (e.g VALUE_LIMITPRODUCT and VALUE_LIMITCATALOG work), the one with PERCENT_LIMITPRODUCT is not working correctly and are obviously wrong (replace?). The ideal goal is to have the percentage value applied and detracted to the grand total.

What is the best way to having this achieved? Some expert insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you show us some HTML? Specifically, where the `.grand-total` element(s) are?  I think you're going to have to do some string-to-double (`parseFloat()`), calculate the value, and then assign that value as the HTML for that element.  Also, if it's one specific element, I'm not sure that referencing it by class name is the best approach (give it an ID, and reference by ID instead)

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that a positive percentage value means a reduction in the total value you could use something like the following:

```
if (response) {
  var rJson = JSON.parse(response).result,
      ty=rJson.valueType,
      va=rJson.value;
  console.log(rJson);
  var discountValue
  if(ty == 'VALUE') {
      discountValue = va;
  }
  else if (ty == 'PERCENT_LIMITPRODUCT') {
      discountValue = $('.grand-total').text().replace('$','')*(-va/100.+1);
  }
  else if (ty == 'VALUE_LIMITPRODUCT' || ty == 'VALUE_LIMITCATALOG') {
      discountValue = va;
  ...
```

I second @Tyler Sells' comment. Without knowing the *actual* HTML this can only be a rough guess. In my code the `parseFloat()` conversion on `va` is done implicitly by applying the minus sign. This will of course only work if there *is* a sensible value to be converted in the first place. The conversion of the `grand-total` amount is done by applying the multiplication. But this too might fail if the content is "not convertible".

Response:

```
    result:
    code: "SIERRATEST4"
    internalNotes: ""
    issueDate: "2019-10-02T17:00:00Z"
    status: "ISSUED"
    value: 10
    valueType: "PERCENT_LIMITPRODUCT"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. However when using your method on the Percentage code, the result is : Promo Code -$NaN

Comment: That might be so, but I have not done anything with `promo code` ;-) ! Can you share what `console.log(rJson)` delivers?

Comment: Could you edit your post and include the response there please? The unformatted code is hard to read in the comment section and we might misinterpret it. And, could you give us an example of what `$('.grand-total').text()` delivers?

Comment: You edited *my* post, but it helped nonetheless! :D  The problem seems to originate from the `grand-total` value though ...